# C# Regex match + next n characters

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regex and i need to parse sourcecode from a website. Can anyone tell me what would be the syntax to match a word followed by the next n characters in the string.

Let's say I wanna match word "country" followed by the next 15 chars in the string.

If string would be "...<tr class="hover"><td>country</td><td>RO</td></t......" I need to get "country</td><td>RO" , I can deal with the string like this , ideally would be only "country RO " but I don't wanna ask for too much.

Comment: You will get better help if you show some initiative of your own first before asking a question.  Show what you have tried, and where you fell short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like: `(country)<\/td><td>(\.\.)`

Using $1 $2 as your output should give you what you need.

Explaination:

1. Putting the () brackets around something lets you back reference it with the $1, etc.
2. Otherwise you are able to match exact characters.
3. Note to escape special regex chars like / with a backslash
4. The second match in brackets is just matching the next two characters no matter what they are. If you have a subset these can be (i.e. [A-Za-z]) it would be better to use that

With that assumption I would use something like: `(country)<\/td><td>([A-za-z]{2})`

Also helps to find a good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: thank you for the useful info. i see now that the syntax for this was quite obvious but i couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your flavor of Regex engine:

```
"country.{15}"
```

Should match "country" exactly, followed by 15 characters of any kind.

It's worth noting that this is an exact match. If there aren't exactly 15 characters following the words "country" this match will fail. That could be problematic for you.

```
"country.{1,15}"
```

This will match "country" exactly followed by any character (up to 15). Again, this could also be problematic depending on your use case.

Comment: thank you , this should do it. works fine and won't be any problems since i have plenty chars after it, like hundreds.